# Core Data duplicating managed object after changing properties

Tags: ios, core-data, nsmanagedobject, nsmanagedobjectcontext

Consider that I have an arbitrary object on a context.

I'm creating a new context with a parent context that has this object.

```
context2 = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSMainQueueConcurrencyType];
context2.parentContext = parentContext;
```

On this new context I do something like this in order to change the object on it's own context:

```
NSManagedObjectID *objectID = [managedObject objectID];
NSManagedObject *contextObj = [context2 objectWithID:objectID];
```

if I do a fetch on the context now, it only displays 1 object, which is expected. But once I do
`contextObj.name = @"blah";`
the same fetch not returns 2 objects

One has the original name, the other has "blah";

And the one with the original name has `isTemporary` on it's objectID set to YES, but the one with "blah" has it set to NO.

any idea on why the context is making a copy of the object with the old value?

Ex:

```
NSManagedObjectContext *context2 = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSMainQueueConcurrencyType];
context2.parentContext = parentContext;

NSManagedObject *contextObj = [context2 objectWithID: myObject.objectID];
//If I do a NSFetchRequest here on the context2, there's only 1 object

contextObj.name = @"test";
//Now, the fetch has 2 objects
```

Edit:
Here's a code that replicates the issue:

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "CustomObject+CoreDataClass.h"
#import "SecondCustomObject+CoreDataClass.h"
#import "AppDelegate.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSManagedObjectContext *secondContext;
@property (nonatomic, strong) SecondCustomObject *secondObject;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSPersistentContainer *persistentContainer;

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UIButton *button = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100, 100, 250, 100)];
    [button setTitle:@"Tap here multiple times" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [button setTitleColor:[UIColor redColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [button addTarget:self action:@selector(triggerIssue) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [self.view addSubview:button];

    AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    self.persistentContainer = appDelegate.persistentContainer;

    [self setupConfig];
}

- (void)setupConfig {
    NSManagedObjectContext *firstContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSMainQueueConcurrencyType];
    firstContext.parentContext = self.persistentContainer.viewContext;
    firstContext.mergePolicy = NSMergeByPropertyObjectTrumpMergePolicy;

    self.secondContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSMainQueueConcurrencyType];
    self.secondContext.parentContext = firstContext;
    self.secondContext.mergePolicy = NSMergeByPropertyObjectTrumpMergePolicy;

    self.secondObject = [[SecondCustomObject alloc] initWithContext:self.secondContext];
    self.secondObject.name = @"Name1";
}

//Needs to be triggered 2-3 times for the issue to happen
- (void)triggerIssue {
    [self.secondContext performBlock:^{
        [self.secondContext save:NULL];
        [self.persistentContainer.viewContext performBlock:^{
            [self.persistentContainer.viewContext save:NULL];
            NSLog(@"SAVED");
        }];
    }];

    [self.secondContext.parentContext refreshAllObjects];
    [self.secondContext.parentContext save:NULL];
    self.secondObject.name = @"Name2";
    [self print];
}

- (void)print {
    NSArray *result = [self.secondContext executeFetchRequest:SecondCustomObject.fetchRequest error:NULL];
    NSLog(@"Result Count [%lu]", (unsigned long)result.count);
    for (SecondCustomObject *obj in result) {
        NSLog(@"Obj Name [%@]", obj.name);
    }
    NSLog(@"-----");
}
```

After calling `triggerIssue` some times, you start to see duplicated objects on the same context, here's an output example:

```
CDTest[15510:761956] Result Count [1]
CDTest[15510:761956] Obj Name [Name2]
CDTest[15510:761956] -----
CDTest[15510:761956] SAVED
CDTest[15510:761956] Result Count [1]
CDTest[15510:761956] Obj Name [Name2]
CDTest[15510:761956] -----
CDTest[15510:761956] SAVED
CDTest[15510:761956] Result Count [2]
CDTest[15510:761956] Obj Name [Name2]
CDTest[15510:761956] Obj Name [Name2]
CDTest[15510:761956] -----
CDTest[15510:761956] SAVED
```

Comment: Have you saved the changes before you perform the fetch. Can you show more complete code; a [mcve]?

Comment: Yes, the parent context has no pending changes. I've added the code with the same flow I have on my project. I'll try to create a sample project and isolate the case, but the problematic part is what I copied there. Consider the parent context without pending changes and only one object saved on the persistent store

Comment: I tried to replicate your problem but I can't - I only ever have a single object in the parent and child contexts; This is why it would help if you provided a complete example with all relevant code that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: You're right, I'm pretty sure there's something else affecting this piece of code, once I create the sample project that can be used to replicate the issue I'll post here, just didn't have the time to do it yet. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @Paulw11 I was able to isolate the issue and make it 100% reproducible.

Answer (score 0):

You should not call `save` on the parent context in your `performBlock`.  The `save` on your second context propagates your changes to the parent context.

Once the block has been performed and the changes propagated you can save your main context.

Removing these lines

```
 [self.persistentContainer.viewContext performBlock:^{
        [self.persistentContainer.viewContext save:NULL];
        NSLog(@"SAVED");
    }];
```

from the block resolves the problem.  The `save` performed outside the `performBlock` saves the view context.

Comment: This code is not supposed to make much sense in a way of using on a real project, but trying to demonstrate a side-effect. The side-effect that I'm not understanding, why is the object duplicated? And why does it takes 3-4 times for it to happen?

Just to be clear, I'm not trying to solve this problem, I know there are better architectures to use parent/child context and avoid this from happening, but I'm trying to understand why it happens. Still not clear to me.

Comment: To get the precise answer you would have to see exactly what is going on inside `performBlock`. There is an auto release pool in use and there is an update made to the parent context. I guess there is some sort of race condition that is being caused by persisting the changes to the persistent store before all of the cleanup from `performBlock` is done.  The code you have is not correct and by fixing it the issue goes away.